# XYSeries autorange loss of precision?

Tags: jfreechart

I'm creating an `XYSeries` in JFreeChart 1.0.17 as shown below, and building a chart out of it dynamically. The x, y data that are added can be of any magnitude, but when the x and y values are very small fractions -- 1e-5 or less -- the autorange calculations seem not to work, and the plot produced will be just a flat line. In this case multiplying all the data by a factor of 10,000 before adding them to the series leads to a correct plot. The data are added as doubles, and I've looked at the XYSeries object in a debugger to make sure the correct values are ending up there. Am I missing something? Is there some way to help the autorange calculations do the right thing?

```
series = new XYSeries("Heartbeat");
final XYSeriesCollection data = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("", "", "", data, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
ValueAxis domain = plot.getDomainAxis();
domain.setAutoRange(true);
((NumberAxis) domain).setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
ValueAxis range = plot.getRangeAxis();
range.setAutoRange(true);
((NumberAxis) range).setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ValueAxis class has an autoRangeMinimumSize attribute which defaults to 0.00000001.  When the range is automatically calculated, the axis won't let it go below this size.  It is intended for the case where all your data values are the same, in which case it determines the axis length.  But as you've found, it causes problems if all your data values are less than 0.00000001, so you should set it to something lower instead of using the default.